# Listing Number Of Rows based on Quantity

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query running on SQL Server 2008 and I am facing a problem that it exceeds the `maxrecursion` limitation, and I don't know an alternative way to do it.

Let me explain this: this query is listing the number of rows for each `MfgPN` based on the `ShipQuantity`.

For example, if `MfgPN` is `XYZ` and `ShipQuantity` is 5, it will return 5 rows... and so on for other `MfgPN` base...etc.

This was working fine until recently I received records have `ShipQuantity` that is over 100K, and it crashes because I believe the `maxrecursion` only allow up to 32K.

Please let me know if there is another way to do this that can return more than 100K rows?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Here is the code.

```
WITH feedInfo AS 
(
    SELECT 
        df1.dfID, MfgPN, LinkID, ShipQuantity, 
        df1.ShipDescription, df1.Description, 1 AS Number 
    FROM 
        EXT_Feed df1
    WHERE 
        1 = 1
        AND df1.mfgPN IN ('XYZ') 
        AND df1.InvoiceDate = '2015-12-07'
        AND df1.dfID = '2666'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        df2.dfID, df2.MfgPN, df2.LinkID, df2.ShipQuantity,
        df2.ShipDescription, df2.Description, feedInfo.number + 1 AS Number 
    FROM 
        EXT_Feed df2
    INNER JOIN 
        feedInfo ON df2.dfID = feedInfo.dfID
    WHERE 
        1 = 1
        AND number < feedInfo.ShipQuantity
        --AND df2.MfgPN = feedInfo.MfgPN
        AND df2.mfgPN IN ('XYZ')
        AND df2.InvoiceDate = '2015-12-07'
        AND df2.dfID = '2666'
)
SELECT * 
FROM feedInfo
OPTION (maxrecursion 30000)
```

Comment: This is probably bad advice, but `maxrecursion 0` will remove the recursion limit.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @sstan. I will use that if there is no other better advice from others.

Comment: Not sure how this query is being used, but it just seems to me like what you are trying to do using a recursive CTE would best be achieved in some client side logic.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  It looks like the same data except for the feedInfo.number.

Comment: The solution "maxrecursion 0" works for me.  Basically, for every record in the report, I use the ShipQuantity and transform them to the number of rows,  then after that I insert them into another table with detail information.. Thanks @Steve

Comment: The problem you are going to have with that is that you will eventually run out of memory, tempdb or both.  I would suggest going another method; maybe a trigger at runtime that does what you are doing above for a given  ID or if you are settled on a batch operation, use some kind of looping mechanism.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good idea. Rearchitecting in some way that avoids having to expand the rows is almost certainly going to be a better long-term solution. If it's unavoidable, do it as close to the client as possible, as late in the code or pipeline as possible.

Comment: put simply: it should not be necessary to store a row for each unit shipped. How would you deal with grains of sand?

Comment: Each unit shipped has its own serial#.... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I can propose 2 solutions. First is a fix, second is better. Use what appropriate for you.

1. `MAXRECURSION 0`

Don't afraid too much `MAXRECURSION 0` if you're sure that your query correctly ends.

This query executes on my notebook in 22 seconds:

```
WITH SampleValue AS(
SELECT
    id = 1
    ,ShipQuantity = 1000000 -- One million iterations is not problem
),
REC AS(
    SELECT id, ShipQuantity, number = 1
    FROM SampleValue
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
            id, ShipQuantity, number = REC.number + 1
        FROM 
            REC 
        WHERE
            ShipQuantity > number
)
SELECT TOP(10) * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM Rec
)S
ORDER BY number DESC    
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

2. **Much better solution**

Create table NUMBERS in your database and populate it with values 1..1000000.
This is common technique in report databases.

```
CREATE TABLE NUMBERS(number int PRIMARY KEY);

WITH REC AS(
    SELECT NUMBER = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
            number = REC.number + 1
        FROM 
            REC 
        WHERE
            NUMBER < 1000000
)
INSERT INTO NUMBERS
SELECT NUMBER FROM REC
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

After that you don't need recursion in your queries. You can just write:

```
SELECT 
        df1.dfID, MfgPN, LinkID, ShipQuantity, 
        df1.ShipDescription, df1.Description, N.Number 
    FROM 
        EXT_Feed df1
        JOIN Numbers N ON df1.ShipQuantity <=N.Number
```

Comment: for the 1st solution, I tried to follow your logic but I got stuck.  All I see is the "Select REC" as the table, where can I fit my "EXT_Feed" in this query?  Now, for the 2nd solution, I have inserted 1 million records for numbers, but I ran the query with JOIN, it took forever and the last N.Number column actually started with the ShipQuantity value and increase 1.  Example. my ShipQuantity is 150,000, returns 1st record 150,000, and 2nd row is 150,001 and keep running... up to 600,000+.. then I stopped it.  I am interested to see if it works.

Comment: 1st: I'm just telling you not to be afraid of MAXRECURSION 0. Risk of crashing your server not much higher than with normal queries.

Comment: For Numbers table: you will have exactly the same quantity of rows as with recursive query. But it must work much more efficient, because you've made all calculations before.

Comment: I see. "exactly the same quantity of the rows" will not work for me because the ShipQuantity are different every time.  Thanks away for taking time to help.

Comment: @Milacay: you mean that ShipQuantity is different in every row. So for recursive query you have ShipQuantity rows accordingly to `number < feedInfo.ShipQuantity` (in fact ShipQuantity +1 from anchor select),  and for `JOIN Numbers N ON df1.ShipQuantity <N.Number` you have the same quantity.

Comment: says I have two records. First record has MfgPN = "ABC" and ShipQuantity = "10", then second record has MfgPN = "XYZ" and ShipQuantity = "5".  My query results a total of 15 rows.  It will list 10 rows for "ABC" and 5 rows for "XYZ"...etc.

Answer (score 0):

Every recursive query can be written as a loop (with care). Your recursive query has an anchor part and a recursive part; it can be refactored as:

1. Take the two queries out of the CTE structure.
2. Change the first (anchor) to put its result into a #temp table
3. Change the second (recursive) such that it joins that #temp table to the "child" records instead of calling the CTE recursively (it's just inner join #temp in place of inner join feedinfo)
4. Add a counter tracking the "level" starting from 0
5. Wrap the second query into a while loop so it keeps on running as long as records are returned.

You should end up with this pattern (pseudocode):

```
select <original anchor query>, level = 1 into #temp
set @level = 0

while records are returned (perhaps @@rowcount > 0)
begin
  set @level += 1
  insert into #temp select #temp join <original recursive query> where level = @level
end
```

Comment: I am little lost on this method, but I will play around some more to see if I can get the same result.  Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing this out as a possible solution.  The idea is to get a set number of detail or order lines inserted to another table equal to the quantity entered.  This is one of those things that would work best as a trigger or as a separate stored procedure for the insert of the detail table.

**This is a triggered solution**. I basically took your CTE and limited the recursion based on the QTY and stuck it in an AFTER INSERT trigger.

```
    --CREATE TABLES
    if object_id('shippingTest','U') is not null
        drop table shippingTest;

    create table shippingTest(shipID int identity, mfrID int, shipQty int);
    GO


    if object_id('shippingTestDetail','U') is not null
        drop table shippingTestDetail

    create table shippingTestDetail (detailID int identity, shipID int, mfrID int, shipQty int, detailLineNum int);
    GO

    --CREATE TRIGGER ON INSERT
    CREATE TRIGGER tr_shippingTest_Insert_shippingTestDetail 
    ON shippingTest
    AFTER INSERT 
    AS 
    BEGIN 
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        with cteQty --original cte with recursion limited by shipQty
        as
        (
            select shipID, mfrID, shipQty, 1 as lineNum
            from inserted
            union all
            select i.shipID, i.mfrID, i.shipQty, c.lineNum+1 as lineNum
            from inserted i
                JOIN cteQty c on c.shipID=i.shipID
            where c.lineNum < i.shipQty
        )
        insert shippingTestDetail
        select shipID, mfrID, shipQty, lineNum
        from cteQty
        order by shipID
    END
    GO

    --INSERT VALUES
    insert shippingTest
    values (111,1),(222,2),(555,5)

    select * from shippingTest
    select * from shippingTestDetail order by shipid
```

**This is a stored procedure solution**.  Since you are running a report and then an insert (if I'm following the question correctly.  Does basically the same thing but loops a call to an SP with the shipID as a parameter.

```
--CREATE TABLES
if object_id('shippingTest','U') is not null
    drop table shippingTest;

create table shippingTest(shipID int identity, mfrID int, shipQty int);
GO


if object_id('shippingTestDetail','U') is not null
    drop table shippingTestDetail;

create table shippingTestDetail (detailID int identity, shipID int, mfrID int, shipQty int, detailLineNum int);
GO


--INSERT VALUES
insert shippingTest
values (111,1),(222,2),(555,5);

select * from shippingTest;
go


--create proc to insert detail records
if object_id('usp_insert_shippingTestDetail','P') is null
    exec sp_executesql N'create proc usp_insert_shippingTestDetail as select getdate() STUB';
go

alter proc usp_insert_shippingTestDetail (@shipID int)
as

    with cteQty --original cte with recursion limited by shipQty
    as
    (
        select shipID, mfrID, shipQty, 1 as lineNum
        from shippingTest 
        where shipID = @shipID
        union all
        select st.shipID, st.mfrID, st.shipQty, c.lineNum+1 as lineNum
        from shippingTest st
            JOIN cteQty c on c.shipID=st.shipID
        where c.lineNum < st.shipQty
    )
    insert shippingTestDetail
    select shipID, mfrID, shipQty, lineNum
    from cteQty
    order by shipID
go

--loop through records and insert per shipID
declare @shipID int

--initialize variables

select @shipID = min(st.shipID)
from shippingTest st
    left join shippingTestDetail std on std.shipID = st.shipID
where std.shipID is NULL;

while @shipID is not null
begin   
    exec usp_insert_shippingTestDetail @shipID;

    select @shipID = min(st.shipID)
    from shippingTest st
        left join shippingTestDetail std on std.shipID = st.shipID
    where std.shipID is NULL;
end

select * from shippingTestDetail order by shipid;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to put together the examples, really appreciated.  I tried your solution with stored procedure and it works almost the same with my post.  I didn't use loop, but I bulk insert into the detail table from selecting everything from the result.  Also, your procedure needs to include "OPTION (maxrecursion 0)" at the end; otherwise, it will fail if you have ShipQty over 32,000.